# Как реализовать такую выборку SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT shop_product.id, shop_product_skus.count 
  FROM shop_product, shop_product_skus 
 WHERE shop_product.id=shop_product_skus.product_id 
   AND shop_product_skus.count >= 3 
   AND shop_product.id IN (14770, 13287, 14160, 13906)
```

Возвращает записи с count >= 3.
Можно ли средствами SQL задать значение в выводе 0 всем остальным записям, которые < 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT shop_product.id, 
       case when shop_product_skus.count < 3 
         then 0 
         else shop_product_skus.count  
       end count
  FROM shop_product, shop_product_skus 
 WHERE shop_product.id=shop_product_skus.product_id     
   AND shop_product.id IN (14770, 13287, 14160, 13906)
```

Comment: Ну или как вариант `(shop_product_skus.count >= 3) * shop_product_skus.count AS count`... :)

Comment: @Akina ну это уже издевательство над теми, кому это придется читать. Да и работать оно будет медленнее)